# Using an HttpRequest as a global variable

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've got the following code:

```
namespace CST
{
    public partial class frmBenefitSummaryList : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        public string PlanID = Convert.ToString(Request.QueryString["PlanID"]);
        public string AuditID = Convert.ToString(Request.QueryString["AuditID"]);


        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack = true;
            BindAccordions();

            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                LoadIssues();
                LoadResolutions();
                LoadNetworks();
                LoadStatus();
            }

        }
etc...
```

What I need to do is use PlanID and AuditID in other parts of my code.  However, when I try to make them public (as I have in the above code), I get an error:

> A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method or
>   property 'Page.Request'

Any idea how to make those variables global?

For the record, I'm opening this page from another page using

```
        String SUrl = "frmSummary.aspx?PlanID=" + PlanID + "&AuditID=" + AuditID;
        Server.Transfer(SUrl, true);
```

Comment: C# doesn't have the concept of global variables. You can create public static variables, which are not able to access instance variables (you could however assign the values in an instance method). But in this case, it sounds like an XY Problem. Static variables in a page class are a sign that you're doing something really wrong.

Comment: You do not want global or static variables in this case especially since you are dealing with web requests which can handled simultaneously. With a global/static variable you would get unexpected results because the value would be overwritten by whatever request just happened to start execution. Instead pass the values in as parameters to your other classes/methods as you need them.

Comment: If you need those values to persist between page requests, you could set them as Session variables instead.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm self-taught.  I have to filter some data based on a user's input, and bind that data to a grid.  In order to get the user's selection into 'BindAccordions()', I need to make them global.  I think.

Comment: @mason - the underlying issue is that the OP is trying to access the Request object in the property initializer. Instead it should be moved to the `Page_Load` method. Once that is done the could could work with either class scoped field/property or as instance variables passed to the method. B2K had the right idea, I just read over it, although personally I would always choose for variables scoped to the method over class fields/properties unless otherwise necessary (and I do not believe it is based on the code shown).

Comment: Someone told me to pass them into BindAccordions, like 'BindAccordions(int PlanID, int AuditID)'.  I did that and it worked perfectly.  I don't see that comment here anymore, but Thank You to whomever suggested that!

Comment: @JohnnyBones That was Igor, and that comment is still here (it's the 2nd comment)

Comment: So, I'm still frustrated that I've got a downvote for a perfectly legitimate answer. Come on, really?

Comment: Wasn't me, B2K.  I never downvote unless I know something is bunk, and since I don't know C# all that well I wouldn't do that.  I appreciate your willingness to answer an obviously (and admittedly) n00b question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ... I have to filter some data based on a user's input, and bind that data to a grid. In order to get the user's selection into 'BindAccordions()'...

Change your signature of `BindAccordions()` to `BindAccordions(int planId, int auditId)` and then pass them in when you call the method

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // note there is a null/empty check on the query string parameters and a default of 0 will be used if no value is included
  // it does not protect against unexpected values like "ABC"
  // if 0 is encountered and its not expected then you can return an error message or something else

  var planId = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Request.QueryString["PlanID"])
    ? 0
    : int.Parse(Request.QueryString["PlanID"]);

  var auditId = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Request.QueryString["AuditID"])
    ? 0
    : int.Parse(Request.QueryString["AuditID"]);

  if (!Page.IsPostBack) {
    // existing code before left unchanged ...
    BindAccordions(planId, auditId);
    // existing code after left unchanged ...
  }
```

---

The underlying reason for the Exception as pointed out in `@B2K`'s answer is that you were trying to use class level property in your property initializer but this is not allowed because there is no guarantee that the property (Request) itself  has been initialized yet when your initializer runs.

Best practice though is to limit scope whenever possible, so in this case passing in values into your methods is considered best practice as it limit the scope of those variables.

Comment: This happened to work for me, and based on some banter above I assume it's at least an acceptable way to go about it if I need to do this again.  Thanks!

Comment: @Igor should those parameters be int or string? His original post has them as strings. Also as the accepted answer, please provide details on how to obtain the values. I know it's in my answer, but better to be thorough. Great discussion btw.

Comment: They actually had to be converted to int, it turns out, so Igor's answer is correct.  That was my bad, I didn't find out until I put this into place.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are referencing the Request object before it is getting set. Try this instead:

```
public partial class frmBenefitSummaryList : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private string PlanID;
    private string AuditID;


    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PlanID = Request["PlanID"];
        AuditID = Request["AuditID"];

        this.MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack = true;
        BindAccordions();

        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            LoadIssues();
            LoadResolutions();
            LoadNetworks();
            LoadStatus();
        }

    }
```

Comment: @Igor there is no static keyword on those fields. His intent is that he wanted them static, that's not what he did. And he's referencing page.request before it is getting set. Did you notice the error message he got: `A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method or property 'Page.Request'`?

Comment: @mason Did you actually see a static keyword on those properties?

Comment: If you read the error message then it's clear that he did have static on there. I know it's not in your answer, but that doesn't mean that having instance level fields are the proper solution here. Instance level fields should be used to store the state of a page, not used to circumvent proper logic. The thing to do here would be to pass `PlanID` and `AuditID` to the methods that need them.

Comment: @mason Instance level variables exist for the purpose of being accessible to the methods of that instance. The issue isn't that he used instance variables, the issue was that he was trying to set them too soon. I disagree that it is proper to explicitly list all the properties to a method. Consider the Page_Load method as an example. It does not require you to pass a Request or Session object to it. Those are instance variables of the Page class.

Comment: @B2K That's because Page_Load doesn't always need `Request` or `Session`. But if `BindAccordions` needs those to function, then it makes sense to include them as parameters. Your way works of course, I just feel like it's important to teach good programming techniques so people get started on the right foot.

Comment: @mason We differ on what constitutes good programming practice. That's a topic for a different site. I've been programming for 33 years and find that `cleanliness is next to godliness` as far as coding goes. Nothing wrong with instance variables. Even static variables have valid uses, but not for this purpose. If you'd like to continue this discussion, I'd suggest we move that to http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/